# Why would putting a no-op Converter on a Binding change its behavior?

Tags: wpf, binding, user-controls, ivalueconverter

I'm in the midst of testing a user control I've built, and I'm encountering something that's inexplicable to me.

The control's an extension of the ComboBox that handles values of a specific custom type.  It has a dependency property of that custom type that is the target property of a Binding.

I've got a trace statement in the setter, and I can see that the property is getting set.  But it's not appearing in my user control.

Now, ordinarily I'd say, okay, I've got a bug in my user control.  I probably do, though I'm baffled about it.  But this question isn't about finding the bug in my control.  Read on; here is where it gets weird.

I'm also using Bea Stollnitz's little value converter to help debug the Binding:

```
public class DebuggingConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return value; // Add the breakpoint here!!
    }
    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException("This method should never be called");
    }
}
```

The idea behind this is that I add this converter to my Binding and can set a breakpoint to see what value is being pushed out to the target.  Okay, that works just fine.  I can see that the value is being pushed out.

In fact, it works a little *too* fine.  If the DebuggingConverter is attached to the Binding, the user control displays the value.  If it's not, it doesn't.

How is that even possible?  How could a value converter that does nothing affect the behavior of a bound control?

**Edit:**

Not that it's likely to help, but here's the XAML for the user control:

```
<a:CodeLookupBox
    Grid.Column="1"
    Grid.IsSharedSizeScope="True"
    MinWidth="100"
    Style="{Binding Style}">
    <a:CodeLookupBox.CodeLookupTable>
        <Binding Path="Codes" Mode="OneWay"/>
    </a:CodeLookupBox.CodeLookupTable>
    <a:CodeLookupBox.SelectedCode>
        <Binding Path="Value" Mode="TwoWay" ValidatesOnDataErrors="True"/>
    </a:CodeLookupBox.SelectedCode>
</a:CodeLookupBox>
```

Without the converter on the second binding, the control behaves as though I didn't set `SelectedCode`.  Even though a trace statement in the `OnSelectedCodePropertyChanged` handler shows that `e.Value` does indeed contain the correct value.  This happens irrespective of whether the converter's attached or not.

I've been trying to reverse-engineer this problem with a thought experiment:  if you wanted to create a bound user control whose behavior changed if a no-op converter were attached to its binding, how would you do it?  I don't know enough about binding to come up with an answer.

Comment: This is very interesting.  Any way you could paste some XAML in there to show the bindings?

Comment: That's a good question. I don't have an answer, but I know the post on Bea's site gives some other advice about debugging bindings. Are any exceptions thrown when you aren't using the converter?

Comment: Sorry I can't help you, but +1 cause that DebuggingConverter is a cool idea (even though it's not your idea).

Comment: Is there anything in the `Validation.Errors` attached property for the target object of the second binding when you don't use the converter?

Comment: Does it work if you change the second binding to OneWay?

Comment: No on the validation errors, no on changing the binding mode to OneWay.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the good news is, I know why `SelectedCode` isn't being set when I'm not using a value converter.  The bad news is, I still have something of a mystery, but the problem's been pushed up the food chain a bit, and I have a workaround.

This control is essentially a strongly-typed combo box with a bunch of additional features that are made possible by the fact that it knows what kind of items are in it.  The `SelectedCode` and `CodeLookupTable` properties are strongly typed, and they hide the underlying `SelectedItem` and `ItemsSource` properties, which aren't.  (This, by the way, is why this is a user control and not a subclass of `ComboBox`; I don't want those properties to be visible because a lot of things can happen if they get set improperly, none of them good.)

Here's what's happening.  This is my debugging output when the value converter is attached (the number is the hash code of the control, because I've got a bunch of them that all get drawn simultaneously when the program's initialized):

```
14626603: OnCodeLookupTablePropertyChanged
   CodeLookupTable property set to Proceedings.Model.CodeLookupTable
   box.MainComboBox.ItemsSource = MS.Internal.Data.EnumerableCollectionView
14626603: OnSelectedCodePropertyChanged:
   SelectedCode property set to Unlicensed Driver [VC12500(A)]
   box.MainComboBox.ItemsSource = MS.Internal.Data.EnumerableCollectionView
```

This is the expected behavior.  The `CodeLookupTable` property is set, so setting `SelectedCode` to one of the items in that collection correctly sets `SelectedItem` on the underlying `ComboBox`.

But without the value converter, we get this:

```
16143157: OnSelectedCodePropertyChanged:
   SelectedCode property set to Unlicensed Driver [VC12500(A)]
   box.MainComboBox.ItemsSource = 
16143157: OnCodeLookupTablePropertyChanged
   CodeLookupTable property set to Proceedings.Model.CodeLookupTable
   box.MainComboBox.ItemsSource = MS.Internal.Data.EnumerableCollectionView
```

Here, the `SelectedCode` property is being set *before* the `CodeLookupTable` property is.  So when the method tries to set `SelectedItem` on the underlying `ComboBox`, nothing happens, because the `ItemsSource` is null.

And here is the root of the problem.  I've foolishly assumed that the order that bindings update their target in is the same as the order they're declared in the XAML.  (One of the reasons I've expressed the bindings as elements instead of attributes is because the order of elements in an  XML document is deterministic and the order of attributes isn't.  It's not like I didn't think about this.)  This is apparently not the case.

I've also assumed, maybe a little less foolishly,  that the order in which bindings update their target isn't dependent on whether or not they have attached value converters.  Well, it is.  I wonder what else it depends on.

Mercifully, I have a way to work around this.  Since my `CodeLookup` object contains a reference to the `CodeLookupTable`, I can make the `SelectedCode` setter set the `CodeLookupTable` (and thus the `ItemsSource`) property first, if it hasn't already been set.  That'll make this problem go away without having to stick a fake value converter on the binding and hope that the way bindings behave never changes.

**Edit**

Here's what the property declarations look like:

```
#region SelectedCode

public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectedCodeProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
    "SelectedCode", typeof(CodeLookup), typeof(CodeLookupBox),
    new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(OnSelectedCodePropertyChanged));

private static void OnSelectedCodePropertyChanged(DependencyObject source, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    CodeLookupBox box = (CodeLookupBox)source;
    CodeLookup code = e.NewValue as CodeLookup;
    // this right here is the fix to the original problem:
    if (box.CodeLookupTable == null && code != null)
    {
        box.CodeLookupTable = code.Table;
    }
    box.MainComboBox.SelectedItem = e.NewValue;
}

public CodeLookup SelectedCode
{
    get { return GetValue(SelectedCodeProperty) as CodeLookup; }
    set { SetValue(SelectedCodeProperty, value); }
}

#endregion

#region CodeLookupTable

public static readonly DependencyProperty CodeLookupTableProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
    "CodeLookupTable", typeof(CodeLookupTable), typeof(CodeLookupBox),
    new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(OnCodeLookupTablePropertyChanged));

private static void OnCodeLookupTablePropertyChanged(DependencyObject source,
DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    CodeLookupBox box = (CodeLookupBox)source;
    CodeLookupTable table = (CodeLookupTable)e.NewValue;

    box.ViewSource = new CollectionViewSource { Source = table.Codes };
    box.View = box.ViewSource.View;
    box.MainComboBox.ItemsSource = box.View;

}

public CodeLookupTable CodeLookupTable
{
    get { return GetValue(CodeLookupTableProperty) as CodeLookupTable; }
    set { SetValue(CodeLookupTableProperty, value); }
}

#endregion
```

Comment: Interesting. I assume that `SelectedCode` and `CodeLookup` are DPs. Could you show their declarations and how you pass the changes on to `ItemsSource` and `SelectedItem`?

Answer (score 0):

try to implement the ConvertBack function too, you are using two-way binding so the problem may be that the exception will be ignored by the "xaml" but when you step in debug mode you maybe stop the "send value back"-operation?

Comment: A good idea, so good I already did it.  It changed nothing.  I changed ConvertBack to return `value` and got the same result.  Also, I don't have to be stepping through the debugger in order for the converter to have its effect.  I can be running a release build.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm...very strange. I've seen similar behavior when dealing with MultiBindings with multiple converters, but not on a simple binding. Out of curiosity, how are you defining your DPs on the control? (including the callbacks, metadata options, etc)

Some stuff to try (after removing the converter hook):

- Default the mode (ie, remove the TwoWay)
- Remove the ValidatesOnDataErrors
- Add an AffectsRender to the SelectedCode DP

Answer (score 0):

What does setting SelectedCode do?  Can you post the code for the property changed handler?

You've suggested that debugging shows the property is being set to the correct value, so the most obvious suggestion is that the code providing your intended behaviour is incorrect.